# Open a new git-bash terminal and run commands in it

Tags: bash, git, git-bash

I set up a pre-commit hook to run unit tests in git. This means that everytime I run a git commit command, it will run pytest automatically.

However, this will stall my git-bash terminal for some time.
I would like to have a command that will open a new git-bash window and run git commit -m $mycomment in it automatically.

I know I can run a new git-bash by typing git-bash (as git-bash.exe is in my path), but how do I run a 'git commit $mycomment' after it? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place the commands inside a bash shell script. Let's call it: <script name>.

```
chmod +x <script name>
git-bash -c <script name>
```

I would add a sleep command inside the script so that you can view any results.

Comment: yeah, I thought about this option, but wondered if there was something else, as probably this 'git-bash' command is also gonna be in a script and I didn't want to multiply them needlessly